# CloudFront Lambda@Edge Cache Behavior Not Showing up in AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-lambda-edge

I am perplexed as to how I can associate an AWS Lambda@Edge function with a CFT and not have it show up in the AWS console under 'CloudFront > Functions'.

Is this a different type of association? Do I need to make changes to my CFT? Is it a bug in the AWS console?

CFT snippet:

```
CloudFrontDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Aliases:
          - my.site.dev
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          TargetOriginId: !Sub 'S3-${AWS::StackName}-root'
          LambdaFunctionAssociations:
            -
              EventType: origin-response
              LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref Lambdaversion
```

View of the console:

[image: aws console with no functions shown]

Any thoughts appreciated.

Edit:
If I create a function via the screen above, the generated ARN is:

```
arn:aws:cloudfront::123456789012:function/test
```

so that tells me that there are different types of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a different type of association?

Yes. Lambda@Edge and [CloudFront functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-functions.html) are **different**. If you want to use CloudFront functions you have to create them using [AWS::CloudFront::Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudfront-function.html).

But your code shows that you are using Lambda@Edge which has no relation with CloudFront functions, thus it does not show in that menu.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of a good resource that breaks down the differences/use-cases?

Comment: @mark aws announcement has some more info about the two https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/05/cloudfront-functions/

Comment: @mark How did it go? Still unclear why you can't see your functions in the console?

Comment: thanks for asking. I can see the functions in the CloudFront cache behavior edit screen but I still really have very little grasp as to the difference between Lambda@Edge and CloudFront functions (why would I pick one over the other, what features does one have other the other, debugability, etc)

Comment: @mark Why not make new question for that, which would have more visibility and allowed others to help as well? Your current question is about no Lambda@Edge functions visible in CloudFront console.